# Replacing ActionBar with a toolbar

Tags: android

i'm trying to replace the ActionBar menu in my code with a toolbar .... ive searched the net but i didn't find something clear enough for me . take a look to my code. 
'

```
     private void actionBarConfig() {
     final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
     bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


     ActionBar.Tab TachoTab     = bar.newTab().setText("Tacho");
     ActionBar.Tab OverviewTab  = bar.newTab().setText("†berblick");
     ActionBar.Tab DataLoggerTab= bar.newTab().setText("Data Logger");


     Fragment TachoFragment     = new Tacho_Fragment();
     Fragment OverviewFragment  = new Overview_Fragment();
     Fragment DataLoggerFragment= new DataLogger_Fragment();


     TachoTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(TachoFragment, "Tacho"));
     OverviewTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(OverviewFragment, "Overview"));
     DataLoggerTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(DataLoggerFragment, "DataLogger"));


     bar.addTab(TachoTab);
     bar.addTab(OverviewTab);
     bar.addTab(DataLoggerTab);  
}
```

`

and this is th .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@id/fragment_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0.0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want toolbar so that you can customise it to whatever color you want ryt?
If thats the case here is a wonderful tutorial for that [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMO8EVkhJO8&index=3&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD)

Update 1:

Here is the link to viewPager [ViewPager](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-horizontal-view-swiping-using-viewpager-and-fragmentpageradapter-in-android/)

Comment: yes and i want to use to navigate between several fragments... any idea?

Comment: sure have you checked the link?? how do you want to navigate using navigation drawer or within the  mainActivity itself

Comment: i'm a beginner in android so honestly  don't understand the difference ... but let me describe a little bit my apllication i have three interfaces to show me a car situation (speed, engine tempreture...) for that i have three interfaces : one for tachometer , another with progressbar and finally one with a graph nd i want to use the toolbar to navigate between because the actionbar are deprecated :)

Comment: ok see for your need i think you need viewpager .... wait i will update my answer with a link

please click solve if it solves your problem thank you

Comment: Can you please vote the answer up and click as solved if it helped you